# Counting the results from a left join is only returning 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with users, and another table with their submitted websites. I want to select all user's regardless of whether they have websites in the websites table. If they do, I want to count those for use in my PHP script.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    u.user_country, 
    u.user_id, 
    u.user_email, 
    u.user_verified, 
    c.country_iso, 
    c.country_nicename,  
    count(distinct w.website_id) as websitecount
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN country c
    ON c.country_id = u.user_country
LEFT JOIN websites w
    ON w.website_owner = u.user_id
```

**My user table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_firstname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `user_surname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `user_country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_verified` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**My websites table**

```
CREATE TABLE `websites` (
  `website_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `website_name` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `website_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `website_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `website_verified` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `website_owner` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `website_adult_content` varchar(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now, when I remove `count(distinct w.website_id) as websitecount` from my SQL, it selects all the rows as it should. But with that in, it just selects 1. I am  trying to select all.

Comment: you are missing a `group by`.

Comment: you are missing the `GROUP BY`. I know that mysql allows it (god knows why), but you really should use it

Comment: @Lamak, what does happen if it's missing? Group by all needed columns, or just something unpredictable?

Comment: @jarlh in all honesty, I have no idea because I don't use mysql. But I gather that what happens is what op is saying, that it returns 1 row with some value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to use a `group by` here:

```
SELECT 
    u.user_country, 
    u.user_id, 
    u.user_email, 
    u.user_verified, 
    c.country_iso, 
    c.country_nicename,  
    count(distinct w.website_id) as websitecount
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN country c
    ON c.country_id = u.user_country
LEFT JOIN websites w
    ON w.website_owner = u.user_id 
group by u.user_country, 
    u.user_id, 
    u.user_email, 
    u.user_verified, 
    c.country_iso, 
    c.country_nicename
```

If you don't include a `group by` clause and you are using an aggregate function, MySQL will arbitrarily choose one record to return. A `group by` essentially says "give me every combination of these things", and if you don't have one, MySQL doesn't know what you want but also doesn't tell you that. Other RDBMS don't even allow you to run the query if you don't have a `group by`, but for some reason MySQL has options for whether you want to be reminded if you haven't included this clause in your query. For more information, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing group by. You need to give the same columns what you are looking for in count.

```
SELECT 
    u.user_country, 
    u.user_id, 
    u.user_email, 
    u.user_verified, 
    c.country_iso, 
    c.country_nicename,  
    count(distinct w.website_id) as websitecount
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN country c
    ON c.country_id = u.user_country
LEFT JOIN websites w
    ON w.website_owner = u.user_id
GROUP BY 
    u.user_country, 
    u.user_id, 
    u.user_email, 
    u.user_verified, 
    c.country_iso, 
    c.country_nicename
```

Note: The above query should be good if you need distinct website count

If you are looking for all website count (i.e. with duplicates) need to remove distinct

```
SELECT 
    u.user_country, 
    u.user_id, 
    u.user_email, 
    u.user_verified, 
    c.country_iso, 
    c.country_nicename,  
    count(w.website_id) as websitecount
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN country c
    ON c.country_id = u.user_country
LEFT JOIN websites w
    ON w.website_owner = u.user_id
GROUP BY 
    u.user_country, 
    u.user_id, 
    u.user_email, 
    u.user_verified, 
    c.country_iso, 
    c.country_nicename
```